# SSIS Dataflow Task issue, moving data from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL via ADO.Net

Tags: mysql, ssis

Can you please help me in getting this problem solved..

I'm trying to build a SSIS package where I'm moving the data from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL. 
However I'm getting a weird problem in dataflow task.

It is getting failed when the length of data in a column (varchar) exceeds the length 32chars.. I'm really confused with this message..

SSIS execution results doesn't show any proper message for the failure.

[ADO NET Destination [329]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is:

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component 
"ADO NET Destination" (329) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (332). 
The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The
error is specific to the component,but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Please help...

Comment: what is the data type of source and destination for that column?

Answer (score 1):

That's either a problem with MySql or with the driver you're using. All SSIS knows is that the driver says 'I can't do that'.

The place to start is by manually inserting as record of that kind into the destination db and looking for a more meaningful error.